# every div & designing(full website) repeated multiple time base on data if database have 1 row all div print 1 time if more then more time.why

Tags: php, html, css

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","users");

    $sql="SELECT * FROM users";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $user_id=$row['user_id'];

?>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Admin Panel</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="robots" content="all,follow">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Fontastic Custom icon font-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontastic.css">
    <!-- Google fonts - Poppins -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,700">
    <!-- theme stylesheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.default.css" id="theme-stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom stylesheet - for your changes-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
    <!-- Favicon-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">    
    <!-- Tweaks for older IEs--><!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page">
      <!-- Main Navbar-->
      <header class="header">
        <nav class="navbar">
          <!-- Search Box-->
          <div class="search-box">
            <button class="dismiss"><i class="icon-close"></i></button>
            <form id="searchForm" action="#" role="search">
              <input type="search" placeholder="What are you looking for..." class="form-control">
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-holder d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
              <!-- Navbar Header-->
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <!-- Navbar Brand --><a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">
                  <div class="brand-text brand-big"><span>Admin Panel </span><strong></strong></div>
                  <div class="brand-text brand-small"><strong>AP</strong></div></a>
                <!-- Toggle Button--><a id="toggle-btn" href="#" class="menu-btn active"><span></span><span></span><span></span></a>
              </div>
              <!-- Navbar Menu -->
              <ul class="nav-menu list-unstyled d-flex flex-md-row align-items-md-center">
                <!-- Search-->

                <!-- Logout    -->
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="login.html" class="nav-link logout">Logout<i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <div class="page-content d-flex align-items-stretch"> 
        <!-- Side Navbar -->
        <nav class="side-navbar">
          <!-- Sidebar Header-->
          <div class="sidebar-header d-flex align-items-center">
            <div class="avatar"><img src="img/avatar-1.jpg" alt="..." class="img-fluid rounded-circle"></div>
            <div class="title">
              <h1 class="h4">Mark Stephen</h1>
              <p>Web Designer</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Sidebar Navidation Menus--><span class="heading">Main</span>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li class="active"><a href="show.php"> <i class="icon-home"></i>Show All Record </a></li>
                    <li><a href="tables.html"> <i class="icon-grid"></i>Logout </a></li>

        </nav>
        <div class="content-inner">
          <!-- Page Header-->
          <header class="page-header">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <h2 class="no-margin-bottom">Dashboard</h2>
            </div>
          </header>



            <table><tr><td><?php echo $user_id ?></td></tr></table>




          <!-- Page Footer-->
          <footer class="main-footer">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <p>Appxone &copy; 2017-2018</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                  <p>Design by <a href="https://bootstrapious.com/admin-templates" class="external"><a href="atc.appxone.com" target="_blank" >Appxone</a></p>
                  <!-- Please do not remove the backlink to us unless you support further theme's development at https://bootstrapious.com/donate. It is part of the license conditions. Thank you for understanding :)-->
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </footer>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- JavaScript files-->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/popper.js/umd/popper.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js"> </script>
    <script src="vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/charts-home.js"></script>
    <!-- Main File-->
    <script src="js/front.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

My issue
i have multiple value in database the problem is number of records is 
equal to number of css,html, all text repeated multiple time related to database row means  every div & designing & text repeated multiple time base on data if database have 1 row all div print 1 time if more then more time.why?
thank in advance plz tell me correct anwser and find my error in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're repeating the whole HTML document in `while` loop, do you mean just repeate `<tr><td>$user_id</td></tr>` like this?:

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","users");

    $sql="SELECT * FROM users";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

?>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Admin Panel</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="robots" content="all,follow">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Fontastic Custom icon font-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontastic.css">
    <!-- Google fonts - Poppins -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,700">
    <!-- theme stylesheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.default.css" id="theme-stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom stylesheet - for your changes-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
    <!-- Favicon-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">    
    <!-- Tweaks for older IEs--><!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page">
      <!-- Main Navbar-->
      <header class="header">
        <nav class="navbar">
          <!-- Search Box-->
          <div class="search-box">
            <button class="dismiss"><i class="icon-close"></i></button>
            <form id="searchForm" action="#" role="search">
              <input type="search" placeholder="What are you looking for..." class="form-control">
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-holder d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
              <!-- Navbar Header-->
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <!-- Navbar Brand --><a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">
                  <div class="brand-text brand-big"><span>Admin Panel </span><strong></strong></div>
                  <div class="brand-text brand-small"><strong>AP</strong></div></a>
                <!-- Toggle Button--><a id="toggle-btn" href="#" class="menu-btn active"><span></span><span></span><span></span></a>
              </div>
              <!-- Navbar Menu -->
              <ul class="nav-menu list-unstyled d-flex flex-md-row align-items-md-center">
                <!-- Search-->

                <!-- Logout    -->
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="login.html" class="nav-link logout">Logout<i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <div class="page-content d-flex align-items-stretch"> 
        <!-- Side Navbar -->
        <nav class="side-navbar">
          <!-- Sidebar Header-->
          <div class="sidebar-header d-flex align-items-center">
            <div class="avatar"><img src="img/avatar-1.jpg" alt="..." class="img-fluid rounded-circle"></div>
            <div class="title">
              <h1 class="h4">Mark Stephen</h1>
              <p>Web Designer</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Sidebar Navidation Menus--><span class="heading">Main</span>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li class="active"><a href="show.php"> <i class="icon-home"></i>Show All Record </a></li>
                    <li><a href="tables.html"> <i class="icon-grid"></i>Logout </a></li>

        </nav>
        <div class="content-inner">
          <!-- Page Header-->
          <header class="page-header">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <h2 class="no-margin-bottom">Dashboard</h2>
            </div>
          </header>



<table>
<?php
    while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $user_id=$row['user_id'];
        echo "<tr><td>$user_id</td></tr>";
    }
?>
</table>
          <!-- Page Footer-->
          <footer class="main-footer">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <p>Appxone &copy; 2017-2018</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                  <p>Design by <a href="https://bootstrapious.com/admin-templates" class="external"><a href="atc.appxone.com" target="_blank" >Appxone</a></p>
                  <!-- Please do not remove the backlink to us unless you support further theme's development at https://bootstrapious.com/donate. It is part of the license conditions. Thank you for understanding :)-->
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </footer>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- JavaScript files-->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/popper.js/umd/popper.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js"> </script>
    <script src="vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/charts-home.js"></script>
    <!-- Main File-->
    <script src="js/front.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```